# Jcheckbox value in jtable based event trigger

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I am working with java swings in netbeans.I have a jtable in my form which will be populated with values from mysql database.The table keeps changing dynamically based on which table the user chooses.I have added a column of checkboxes at the end.Now whatever table is displayed i have made only the last column to be editable by overriding is cell editable function.

So now the checkbox column is editable.I want to make few of the remaining columns  to bee editable when the check box corresponding to the row is checked in and i want to make the row to be non editable once the check box is checked out!!

I need help to to do this task.If any other details required Pls do ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"If any other details required pls do ask..."`: Yes, what have you tried so far, and how is it not working?

Comment: i want to know how to edit the isCellEditable(row,col) function so that the rows become editable on selecting a check box and becomes non editable on deselecting the checkbox.  If there are any links or code for listening the checkbox selection event and then triggering the action of making the cells editable and noteditable according to the boolean value of checkbox column it would be helpful.

Comment: You won't find a tutorial that exactly answers your question, but you will find tutorials that deal with individual aspects of your problem, and it will be your job to synthesize all of this together. Look into using a TableModelListener and listen for changes to your model. Identify the location of the change and the type. and if it is the change in a boolean for the check box column, then have the model change the value returned by the `isCellEditable(...)` for the appropriate row and columns.

Comment: I think that perhaps you're premature in coming here for advice since you're not even at the "ask a specific question" stage yet, much less the "create a trial program" stage. I'd read the JTable tutorials, experiment with aspects of your problem, and then come back when you can ask specific questions on where you're stuck.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip.I will try with the TableModelListener and if there are any specific issues will post again.

Comment: you must not use a listener, it's the responsibility of your _model_ to decide about its editability

Comment: @kleopatra: how does the table listen for clicks on the checkboxes though?

Comment: Your code posted as an answer should be posted as an edit to your question. Your DefaultTableModel implementation is wrong. Either use the DefaultTableModel's own internal Vectors or use an AbstractTableModel if you're going to use your own table model data nucleus.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the boolean (aka: "checkbox") of the last model column decides about the editability of the complete row, or am I misunderstanding the setup? _added a column of checkboxes at the end_ and _make few of the remaining columns to bee editable when the check box corresponding to the row is checked_

Comment: @kleopatra, no, you are correct, and I see the mistake in my logic. Thanks again as always!

Answer (score 1):

Kleopatra is right of course -- there's no need for a listener. All you need to do is have the model check the Boolean value held by the last column of the row of interest and return it as the `isCellEditable()` value.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
   public static final String SELECT = "select";
   String tablename;

   public MyTableModel(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames, String tableName) {
      super(rowData, columnNames);
      this.tablename = tableName;
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      if (getColumnName(columnIndex).equalsIgnoreCase(SELECT)) {
         return Boolean.class;
      }
      return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
      if (col == getColumnCount() - 1) 
         return true;
      else
         return ((Boolean) getValueAt(row, getColumnCount() - 1)).booleanValue();
   }

}
```

Which can be tested with:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TestBoolTableModel {
   public static final Integer[][] DATA = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
         { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };
   public static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",
         MyTableModel.SELECT };

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Object[][] rowData = new Object[DATA.length][];
      for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
         rowData[i] = new Object[DATA[i].length + 1];
         for (int j = 0; j < DATA[i].length; j++) {
            rowData[i][j] = DATA[i][j];
         }
         rowData[i][DATA[i].length] = Boolean.FALSE;
      }
      MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel(rowData, COL_NAMES, "My Table");

      JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestBoolTableModel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both..It is working now!!I am extremely greatful to both of you ..Thanks again

Comment: @user2083089: you're welcome. Thanks for getting back to us on this.